# Swift Realm response results are different

Tags: ios, swift, realm

```
let syncServerURL = URL(string: serverUrl + "Combine")!
var configuration = Realm.Configuration()
configuration.encryptionKey = Utility().getKey() as Data
configuration.syncConfiguration = SyncConfiguration(user: SyncUser.current!, realmURL: syncServerURL)

Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: configuration, callback: { realm, error in        
    if let realm = realm {
        let results = realm.objects(Combine.self)
    } else if let error = error {
        print("error ******* \(error)")
        // Handle error that occurred while opening or downloading the contents of the Realm
    }
})
```

I used this asyncOpen method configuration for to get synced realms, the response results are showing same as realm server records.

```
let syncServerURL = URL(string: serverUrl + "Combine")!
var configuration = Realm.Configuration()
configuration.encryptionKey = getKey() as Data
configuration.syncConfiguration = SyncConfiguration(user: current, realmURL: syncServerURL)
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
let results = realm.objects(Combine.self)
```

I used this method configuration for to get synced realms, the response results are not showing same as realm server records. Its showing **incorrect/outdated records**

The above results are different

Answer (score 0):

`asyncOpen()` downloads all changes from the server before calling the callback, while the synchronous constructor returns a local Realm instance immediately and synchronizes in the background. This means that there is no guarantee that the data is up to date.